# OpenGL buffers,glFlush and glutSwapBuffers()

Tags: opengl, buffer, glut

Is there any difference between using, `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);`
with
`glFlush()`

and `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);` with `glutSwapBuffers()`?

By difference, I imply difference in the execution or display of code ?

Comment: The user will see partially rendered scenes with single buffering, because you're writing to the same buffer that the monitor is getting its pixels from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a huge difference on modern platforms, in the sense that compositing window mangers (e.g. Aero on Windows Vista+) effectively own the front-buffer. If you draw single buffered, a buffer swap never occurs, and the end result is that nothing will ever be displayed on the screen.

This also affects some implementations of hybrid GPUs (e.g. Intel integrated + NVIDIA discrete on laptops) even without a compositing window manager. On such a system, the buffer swap operation is what copies the discrete GPU's framebuffer to the integrated for final output.

There is almost no reason to use single-buffered rendering on modern GPUs. It used to be that having to maintain two color buffers ate a lot of memory, which was also a compelling argument against triple-buffering, but these days the amount of memory required for the color buffer is a minute fraction of VRAM.

Comment: Thanks :). I had absolutely no clue about all of this.