# OpenGL function to display house not working

Tags: c++, opengl

This program displays a house using opengl
The output just displays a blank screen and nothing else and nothing I do to change the window position and size works
I dont't know whats wrong

```
#include<Gl/glut.h>
GLfloat square[][2]={{100,200},{100,100},{200,100},{200,200}};//coordinates of the vertices of the square part of the house
GLfloat door[][2]={{125,150},{125,100},{175,100},{175,150}};// coordinates of the door
GLfloat roof[][2]={{50,200},{250,200},{150,300}};// coordinates of the roof
void Myinit()
{
glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0.0,500.0,0.0,500.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

This function is used to display the house :

```
void drawHouse()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glColor3f(0,1,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);  display the square part of the house
glVertex2fv(square[0]);
glVertex2fv(square[1]);
glVertex2fv(square[2]);
glVertex2fv(square[3]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(1,0,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);  display the roof
glVertex2fv(door[0]);
glVertex2fv(door[1]);
glVertex2fv(door[2]);
glVertex2fv(door[3]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(1,0,0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);  display the triangle
glVertex2fv(roof[0]);
glVertex2fv(roof[1]);
glVertex2fv(roof[2]);
glVertex2fv(roof[3]);
glEnd();
glFlush();
}

int main(int argv, char** argc)
   {
     glutInit(&argv,argc);
     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
     glutCreateWindow("House Drawing which rotates\n");
     glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
     glutInitWindowSize(1000,1000);
     Myinit();
     glutDisplayFunc(drawHouse);
     glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: First of all, i think it is better if you would use opengl-version 3.x,second i think that your coordiantes are maybe too big,normally your window goes from -1 to +1 ,both x and y,but thats just a guess

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a double buffered window, the display function has to call `glutSwapBuffers()` at the end. For more details what double buffering means see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949228/opengl-buffers-glflush-and-glutswapbuffers).